# sending http request to my server is incorrect

Tags: angular, httprequest, patch, http-status-code-415

Frontend todo.ts and todo.html
[image]
[image]

Console.log

[image]

Postman
[image]

backend-code  with spring boot //TodoService; function for Update

```
   public Todos updateTodoWithMap(Long id, Map<Object, Object> objectMap) {

        Optional<Todos> todos = todoRepository.findById(id);

        objectMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Todos.class, (String) key);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(field, todos.get(), value);
        });

        return todoRepository.save(todos.get());
    }
```

and frontend with angular http request

```
  updateTodo(id: any, todoData: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.http.patch<Todo>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, todoData)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

I want to send an http patch request to the server, but I get error message 415. what should I do. what is wrong?

Conroller Class from Todo with PatchMapping:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:8100")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth/users")

public class TodosController {

@Autowired
private final TodosService todoService;


public TodosController(TodosService todoService) {
    this.todoService = todoService;
}

@GetMapping("todo")
public List<Todos> getTodos() {
    return this.todoService.getTodos();
}

@PostMapping("todo")
public Todos addTodos(@RequestBody Todos toDos) {
    return this.todoService.addTodo(toDos);
}

/*@PutMapping("todo/{id}")
public Todos update(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long todoId, @RequestBody Todos todosDetail)
        throws NoteNotFoundException {
    Todos updatedTodos = this.todoService.updateTodo(todoId, todosDetail);
    return updatedTodos;
}*/

  @PatchMapping("todo/{id}")
  public Todos updateTodoWithMap(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id, @RequestBody
  Map<Object,Object> objectMap ){    
 return todoService.updateTodoWithMap(id, objectMap); 
  
  }

@DeleteMapping("todo/{id}")
public Boolean delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return this.todoService.delete(id);
}
```

}

Comment: 415 is unsupported media format. Is your Todo object correct? Does it work with Postman?

Comment: yes it works with postman.

Comment: can I see the postman request + console log of the `toDos` item in your backend, please?

Comment: i try again later, I get the error 500. I uploaded a picture of this, see above @Flo

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field de.beuth.starfishbook.model.Todos.appointmentTime to java.lang.String] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field de.beuth.starfishbook.model.Todos.appointmentTime to java.lang.String

Comment: Try to set the Date as string in the same format you do with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

What is baseUrl set to? If it doesn't contain 'todo' you need to add that in the url like this:

```
this.http.patch<Todo>(`${this.baseUrl}/todo/${id}`
```

Comment: my url like this : private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:8443/auth/users/todo';

Comment: Can you show your @Controller annotated class?

Comment: i added the class above

Comment: i try again later, I get the error 500. but in postman works

Answer (score 0):

First I see you expect a reponse of an array of todos, right? So change your frontend like this:

```
return this.http.patch<Todo[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, todoData)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
```

Then the error says `cannot set java.util.Dateto java.lang.String`. So the date was the problem. I have nothing to do with Spring Boot but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61283425/4472932) i found your problem:

> You have correctly set pattern in the Controller Class with the annotation `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`. And please also make sure that you have: imported two required patterns in your Model/Entity Class as:

```
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```

Comment: no, i still get error 500.  I'm loading the code from frontend todo.ts